# Upgrading WSS 3 and Ms Search Server 2008 Express

Tags: sharepoint

I've managed to do the upgrade the Ms Search Server 2008 Express in conjuction with WSS 3 SP1.

According to the http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297193.aspx - "Configure site collections to use the Search Center" section, I think I am missing the procedure to use this.

It said that I need to have different URL (See: 4.Type the address of your Search Center in the text box, for example, http://servername:port.)

So what did I miss here? At the moment, my search seems ok but I don't think I am using the right interface.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed Search Server, did it provision a Search Center?
Because that is where you need to point all site collections' search to.

When you do a search it will append ?k=yourkeyword to the url. (at least that's how it works in MOSS, should be the same here)

Comment: It should have installed it during the product install.
I'm not too familiar with Search Server but since it is SharePoint after all it should work the same way; create a site collection from central administration and choose the proper site template, something like "Search Center".